# linux socket c : send data when other socket close

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Please help me

client :

```
#include<stdio.h> //printf
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>    //socket
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr 
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[1000] , server_reply[2000];

    //Create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected\n");

    //keep communicating with server
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter message : ");
        scanf("%s" , message);

        //Send some data
        if( send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("Send failed");
            return 1;
        }
        memset(message,0,sizeof(message));
          //Receive a reply from the server 
    }

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

server:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>    //write

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , read_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char client_message[2000];

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    //accept connection from an incoming client
    client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connection accepted");

    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(client_sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }
        //Send the message back to client
       puts(client_message);
       fflush(stdout);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

It's source code from a site. I try it and success connect and send message. Problem is when I connect client to server. Then I close server with ctrl + c. I try to send message, why my message send successfully? (when server over). But when I try send message again, connection over. Please help me. I want to only once send, connection over. Not twice.

Comment: The only reliable way to detect disconnections is to attempt to *read* from the socket, in which case the `recv` function should return zero.

Comment: how to do thats?.sorry i am newbe.should i connect other socket.or when i've send message i use recv ? (sorry for my english.)

Comment: You might have to think about your protocol, and how you communicate between the client and the server. Maybe the server should acknowledge every message it gets, by sending a small message back to the client that the client can read?

Comment: thank's. for your help.i will learn again.

Comment: regarding this line: `if(read_size == 0)`,  This will never be true, because the prior `while()` statement exits its' loop if the returned value from the `read()` is == 0.

Comment: regarding this line: ` if(read_size == 0)`, this will never be true, because the prior `while()` statement exits its' loop if the returned value from `read()` is < 0

Answer (score 0):

What happens is this: Your code exits because a SIG_PIPE is raised to indicate a send error. You do not have a signal catcher therefore the default action is to exit,silently!

Try this `send(sock , message , strlen(message) ,MSG_NOSIGNAL)` and read on signals

Comment: thanks. my problem sigpipe solved.but how only once send, connection over (server close with ctrl + c)? not twice send.

Comment: copying from https://seattle.poly.edu/ticket/974 By TCP rules, the only way for a server/client program to know if a server/client has disconnected,is to try to read from the socket. 

So you need to alter your homework for the server to send an OK message everytime it accepts something and the client to expect to read this response back

Answer (score 0):

> but how only once send, connection over (server close with ctrl + c)?
>   not twice send.

While you have no `recv()` call in your client, you can still detect the *Broken pipe* immediately after the first `send()` call following the server termination by getting the pending socket error with `getsockopt(…, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, …)`, as shown for example in [this answer to "How to find the socket connection state in C?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4142038/2413201)
If an error is returned that way, you can `break` your loop and `close()` the socket.