# How do you get notified about TCP Keepalives last probe?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp-keepalive

I want to be able to detect if the connection between the client and the server is lost within a reasonable time on Linux with in C programming language. I did the following:

```
  int flags = 1;
  setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &flags, sizeof(flags));
  int idle = 3;
  int intvl = 1;
  int cnt = 5;
  setsockopt(fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &idle, sizeof(idle));
  setsockopt(fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &intvl, sizeof(intvl));
  setsockopt(fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &cnt, sizeof(cnt));
```

I checked it in Wireshark, and this succesfully turned on TCP keepalive.

I read that this feature does not close after the last keepalive probe automatically, so I assume that there is some way I can check this condition to be able to close the socket manually.

I want to do something like this for every opened sockets file descriptor periodically:

```
if (sentProbes >= cnt) {
  if(fd >= 0){
    close(fd);
  }
  fd = CLOSED_FD;
}
```

I have tried the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142012/how-to-find-the-socket-connection-state-in-c) question from [Simone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/347137/simone), but it did not work. getsockopt returned 0, and error was also 0 even after the last probe.

Is there some kind of signal or flag for this condition or I have to implement my own heartbeat-like feature on application layer?

Comment: Trying to read or write from a socket that's failed the keepalive ping will cause an error, just like any other reason the remote connection goes away, as well as the socket triggering select/poll/etc.

Comment: There is no way to detect when the probes themselves are sent. All you can do is detect when the socket enters an error state once the probing has failed.

Comment: And how can I do that?