# Why does socket send() return successful code in case of cable connection was broken?

Tags: linux, sockets

I sent packets via a TCP socket well continuously. Then, I unplugged the network cable, and found the send() still returns success. Why?
The initiation codes are as:

```
// This function must be called before any other functions called.
/*  Return:
        0: success
        1: init socket fail
        2: send fail
        3: connect fail
*/

int mtMqttInit (const char *id, const char *username, const char *password, const char *hostName, const int tcpPort, unsigned int timeoutSec)
{
    int pktLen;

    mqtt_init(&mtBroker, id);
    mqtt_init_auth(&mtBroker, username, password);

    if (init_socket(&mtBroker, hostName, tcpPort)) {
        if (debug)
            printf ("init_socket()\n");
        return MT_MQTT_INIT_SOCKET_FAIL;
    }

    if (mqtt_connect(&mtBroker) == -1) {
        if (debug)
            printf ("mqtt_connect()\n");
        return MT_MQTT_INIT_CONNECT_FAIL;
    }
    .....
}

void mqtt_init(mqtt_broker_handle_t* broker, const char* clientid) {
    // Connection options
    broker->alive = 300; // 300 seconds = 5 minutes
    broker->seq = 1; // Sequency for message indetifiers
    // Client options
    // .....
    // Will topic
    broker->clean_session = 1;
}
```

The sending code snippet is as:

```
// Send the packet
log_status("to send");
if(broker->send(broker->socket_info, packet, sizeof(packet)) < 
    sizeof(packet)) {
    log_error("send() failed");
    return -1;
}
log_status("send() done");
```

Even in case of cable connection broken, I cannot see "send() faied" message shown. That's, I can't determine if the socket is still valid or not. What's wrong with it?

Comment: What is all the MQTT stuff related to your question? Can you please reduce your example! Is it about sending via a posix socket in UDP or TCP ... I don't have much fun to read all your code to get the info what you are really doing!

Comment: Because `send()` only buffers the data. The connection is only considered broken when the ACK timers time out, which could take quite a long time after the corresponding send.

Comment: I re-state my problem: After unplugging the network connection, the application level communication was broken and the communication can't be resumed after plugging back the network connection.. But as I said, I can't get failure return from send(), so I can't recover the application level communication. What can I do? How can I detect the communication break and how to recover it? The server is not implemented by me.

Comment: I re-state my comment. Because `send()` only buffers the data. If you have a new question, or a new problem such as 'can't recover the application', you need to state it clearly, probably as a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the getsockopt() to check the validity of socket, instead of checking return value from send(). It works. After knowing the socket being invalid, I closed it and re-created.

The codes is from Simone at 
[How to find the socket connection state in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142012/how-to-find-the-socket-connection-state-in-c)

```
int error = 0;
socklen_t len = sizeof (error);
int retval = getsockopt (socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len);

/// ....
if (retval != 0) {
    /* there was a problem getting the error code */
    fprintf(stderr, "error getting socket error code: %s\n", strerror(retval));
    return;
}

if (error != 0) {
    /* socket has a non zero error status */
    fprintf(stderr, "socket error: %s\n", strerror(error));
}
```

Comment: This just returns the last error on the socket. You must be ignoring an error return somewhere. It doesn't return the current state of the connection, as there isn't any such thing in TCP. All this is already stated in your link.