# Is "reading zero bytes" from a socket a valid way for monitoring a TCP/IP disconnect in POSIX C?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, posix

I'm currently reviewing a C application that implements POSIX sockets. This application intermittently checks to see if the connection to the server is valid by reading zero bytes from the socket. It then checks to see if an errno is set to determine whether or not the connection is okay. Is this a robust solution?

```
uint32_t IsConnected()
{
        char dummy[10];
        if(read(global_sockfd, dummy, 0) == -1)
        {
            if(errno != EWOULDBLOCK && errno != EAGAIN)
                return FALSE;
            else
                return TRUE;
        }   
        else
            return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: maybe? Sounds like a periodic heartbeat message is the best way to know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142012/how-to-find-the-socket-connection-state-in-c

Comment: IMHO it is a solid solution. This is cos you take into account that you can only read from the socket when the socket connected. Due to the fact you are not really reading data, the two error codes make sense too. You may check additional error codes like `ENOBUFS`, but I think the currently ones are sufficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not a robust solution, for two reasons.

First, for a connected TCP socket `read` and `recv` will return zero, not −1, after all incoming data has been read and the remote peer has closed its end of the connection (using `close` or `shutdown`).  Your `IsConnected` will return TRUE in this case, which is wrong.

Second, the [specification of `read`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) says (second paragraph of DESCRIPTION; all emphasis mine)

> Before any action described below is taken, and if `nbyte` is zero, the `read` function **may** detect and return errors as described below. In the absence of errors, **or if error detection is not performed**, the `read` function shall return zero and have no other results.

`nbyte` is the third argument, which your `IsConnected` is supplying as zero.  Therefore, depending on the operating system, `IsConnected` might *always* return TRUE, regardless of the state of the socket.

The [specification of `recv`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html) does not say anything about what happens if the `length` argument (equivalent to `nbyte` for `read`) is zero; I think this is probably an oversight and it (and `recvfrom`, `recvmsg`, etc.) is meant to have the same special behavior as `read`.  So changing `read` to `recv` will not fix the problem by itself.  However, I think a complete fix is possible by using `recv` with `MSG_PEEK`:

```
bool is_connected(int sock)
{
    char dummy[1];
    ssize_t nread = recv(sock, dummy, sizeof dummy, MSG_PEEK);
    if (nread > 0)
        return true;    // at least one byte of data available
    else if (nread == 0)
        return false;   // EOF
    else
        return errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN;
}
```

Using `MSG_PEEK` allows you to supply a nonzero length, because the data will not actually be consumed.

Depending on the details of the application and its network protocol, you may also want to consider [enabling TCP keep-alive packets](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/programming.html) on the socket.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. This is explained in [man 2 recv](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html), *Return value* section:

> These calls return the number of bytes received, or -1 if an
> error occurred.  In the event of an error, errno is set to
> indicate the error.
>
> When a stream socket peer has performed an orderly shutdown, the
> return value will be 0 (the traditional "end-of-file" return).
>
> Datagram sockets in various domains (e.g., the UNIX and Internet
> domains) permit zero-length datagrams.  When such a datagram is
> received, the return value is 0.
>
> The value 0 may also be returned if the requested number of bytes
> to receive from a stream socket was 0.

A TCP socket is a stream socket, so as long as you make sure your `recv()`/`read()` call uses a buffer with nonzero size, a zero return indicates the peer has performed an orderly shutdown.

An orderly shutdown is one of two things: closing the socket, or calling [shutdown()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) on it (in this case, with either SHUT_WR or SHUT_RDWR, former indicating it will not send any further data but is able to receive, and the latter indicating it will not send or receive any data).

Comment: Why are you quoting the Linux man page for `recv()` when the question (currently) uses `read()`? [`read()` has different semantics for an attempt to read zero bytes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html):  "Before any action described below is taken, and if `nbyte` is zero, the read() function may detect and return errors as described below. In the absence of errors, or if error detection is not performed, the read() function shall return zero and have no other results."  So a `read()` call of zero bytes can be a complete no-op.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That's POSIX; for Linux, `read()` has the same semantics as `recv()` wrt. shutdown, if nonzero buffer size is used. No need to believe me, just see the man page I linked to.  Also, you might wish to read my answer completely – I know, it is too long for someone as important as you to read in full, but please try –: *so as long as you make sure your recv()/read() call uses a buffer with nonzero size, a zero return indicates the peer has performed an orderly shutdown*.

Comment: Did you even read [the Linux `read()` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)?  It reads: "If `count` is zero, `read()` *may* detect the errors described below.
       In the absence of any errors, or if read() does not check for
       errors, a `read()` with a `count` of 0 returns zero and has no other
       effects."  `read()` on Linux can be a no-op.  Precision matters in programming, especially in C.  At best, this was a sloppy, off-the-cuff answer.  But "I know, it is too long for someone as important as you to read in full, but please try"?!?!  Seriously?

Comment: Fundamentally the issue with this answer is that you're talking about what happens when `read`/`recv` is passed a buffer of _nonzero_ size, but OP's code clearly uses a buffer of size zero.