# No ethernet connection but SSL_write() return true

Tags: c++, c, sockets, ssl, openssl

I want to check if the ssl_write function was able to transmit data correctly.

The ssl_write function returns positive even though there is no internet connection.

I want to do something like this.

```
if (SSL_write(ssl, chars, strlen(chars)) <= 0)
{
  Init();
}

else
{
  ....
}
```

how can it still return positive value even though there is no internet connection ?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4142038/3150802) may provide the functionality you are looking for (check the socket's status via getsockopt()).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: I doubt that this helps. If there was already a detected error with the socket then both `send` and `SSL_write` would fail too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Ah, I see. As opposed to a merely listening server that would not know? Shouldn't that one get a signal, too?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: I don't really understand your last comment. Maybe I try to reiterate my point: either the socket is considered working or not. If not then all of send, SSL_write an getsockopt will show the error, but if it is considered working then none will show the error. Some packet loss including temporary  interruptions of connectivity are not considered an error, since TCP is designed to be robust against this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The getsockopt() answer was concerning sockets that were listened on by a server, as opposed to the OP's use case where a write is attempted. The write will, as you say, fail under the same circumstances a getsockopt() would indicate an error; but the server needs to perform one of them actively in order to detect the fail state. (That's why the linked answer was helpful in the server case but has no benefit here, as you point out.) I was then wondering whether the server would not receive a signal when the socket "stops working". I guess not.

Answer (score 6):

SSL_write just uses the sockets `send` function internally and if this returns success then SSL_write will return success too. `send` will just put the data into the send buffer of the socket and return success if this worked, i.e. if there was enough space in the socket buffer and if the underlying TCP connection was still established. The kernel will then try to deliver the data to the peer. Thus, **neither `send` nor `SSL_write` provide any information if the data were actually transmitted on the wire to the peer or even received by the peer**.

TCP can cope with temporary interruptions of the physical connectivity. It will simply try to retransmit the packets. Only if these retransmits fail often (i.e. no ACK returned by the peer) the TCP connection (and thus the socket) will be considered broken. And only then a `send` will fail, which also means that only then the `SSL_write` will fail.

Comment: Which begs the question whether there is a standard way to find out whether the physical connection underlying the socket is there?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Knowing about the *local* physical connection provides only very limited information since connectivity can be broken somewhere on the way to the final target. TCP detects delivery problems as long data are exchanged since it is expecting acknowledgements for delivery. TCP keep-alive even provides early detection connectivity problems on idle connection by regularly sending some kind of heartbeat packets.

Comment: Sure, but better detect *some* failures (cable removed, WLAN power cycle) than none at all, right?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica And if the cable gets plugged back in?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, or if we go back to the house and have WLAN again. Up to the application to handle hiccups of different severity, isn't it? But good to know that there is one.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich Do I have the possibility to access the buffer contents of the socket?  as a client.

Comment: @tryingBetter: This is a related but different question and thus should better not be asked in a comment. But in short: one cannot access the content but one might access the size of unsent data. How this is done depends on the system, look for SIOCOUTQ or FIONWRITE.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica [You're advocating for something known to be broken half a century ago - literally](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc675):  "In the simplest implementation, SEND would not return control to the
   sending process until either the transmission was complete or the
   timeout had been exceeded. This simple method is highly subject to
   deadlocks and is not recommended."

Comment: @AndrewHenle I was not aware I was suggesting that ;-).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica But that's exactly what you want - fast error indication for a protocol that was designed from the ground up to be transparently reliable.  The fast error indication that you're advocating for will either break that transparent reliability or it will break the protocol itself.  A protocol can't give up immediately at the slightest hiccup if it wants to be reliable.  Do you really want a bunch of application errors every time your wireless LAN or your cell phone's connection drops for a few seconds because of intermittent interference?